# Calculate corner points in map box

Tags: ios, iphone, mapbox

In my project I'm drawing some annotations over the map.For this, I need to know the four corners of map.So, I would like to know if there is an easy way to find the visible rect of currently displayed map. This is achieved in native maps by:

```
MKMapRect mRect = self.mapView.visibleMapRect;
MKMapPoint neMapPoint = MKMapPointMake(MKMapRectGetMaxX(mRect), mRect.origin.y);
MKMapPoint swMapPoint = MKMapPointMake(mRect.origin.x, MKMapRectGetMaxY(mRect)); MKMapPoint nwMapPoint = MKMapPointMake(mRect.origin.x, mRect.origin.y);
MKMapPoint seMapPoint = MKMapPointMake(MKMapRectGetMaxX(mRect), MKMapRectGetMaxY(mRect));
```

For Mapbox, I thought of using projectedBounds and used following code to get corner points:

```
RMProjectedPoint neMapBoxPoint = RMProjectedPointMake(rect.size.width, rect.origin.y);
RMProjectedPoint swMapBoxPoint = RMProjectedPointMake(rect.origin.x, rect.size.height);
RMProjectedPoint nwMapBoxPoint = RMProjectedPointMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y);
RMProjectedPoint seMapBoxPoint = RMProjectedPointMake(rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
```

But, for both case corner points are different and in map box, m getting wrong data.Any idea how this can be done. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `-[RMMapView latitudeLongitudeBoundingBox]`.